# Font Awesome Icon Picker showing font info text next to icon

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, font-awesome

I've got the following code based off of a codepen for material icon picker and am trying to also create one for font awesome.  The icons show up using the below code, but next to the icon is also the name of the icon (i.e. fas fa-home).  If I remove the line '$icon.text(icon);' in the forEach function then the text does disappear but the search no longer works. This is not a problem when I use material icons. What am I missing here?

```
function fontawesomeMarkers() {
var fontawesome_icons = ['fas fa-home', 'fas fa-map-marker-alt', 'fas fa-beer', 'fas fa-flag', 'fas fa-globe'];

$('input[type="text"].use-icon-picker').each(function () {
    // Add the current icon as a prefix, and update when the field changes.
    $(this).before('<i class="icon-picker-prefix prefix"></i>');
    $(this).on('change keyup', function(){
        $(this).prev().text($(this).val());
    });
    $(this).prev().text($(this).val());
    // Append the picker and the search box.
    var $picker = $('<div class="icon-picker"></div>');
    var $search = $('<input type="text" placeholder="Search...">');
    // Do simple filtering based on the search.
    $search.on('keyup', function () {
        var search = $search.val().toLowerCase();
        var $icons = $(this).siblings('.icons');
        $icons.find('i').css('display', 'none');
        $icons.find('i:contains('+search+')').css('display', 'inline-block');
    });

    $picker.append($search);
    // Append each icon into the picker.
    var $icons = $('<div class="icons"></div>');
    function onIconClick() {
        $(this).closest('.icon-picker').prev().val($(this).text()).trigger('change');
    }
    fontawesome_icons.forEach(function (icon) {
        var $icon = $('<i class="custom-icons"></i>');
        var classText = icon;
        $icon.addClass(classText);
        $icon.text(icon);
        $icon.on('click', onIconClick);
        $icons.append($icon);
    });
    // Show the picker when the input field gets focus.
    $picker.append($icons).hide();
    $(this).after($picker);
    $picker.show();
    $(this).on('focusin', function () {
        $picker.show();
    });
});

// Hide any picker when it or the input field loses focus.
$(document).on('mouseup', function (e) {
    var $picker = $('.icon-picker');
    if ($picker.length && !$picker.is(e.target) && !$(e.target).hasClass('use-icon-picker') && $picker.has(e.target).length === 0) {
    $picker.hide();
    }
});
```

};

Comment: well you have no text to look for so contains is going to break since there is no text to compare against. So you will have to change how the search looks for matches.

Comment: $icon.text(icon); sets the text, which is likely why you see the icon name; I believe you have to set it as an attribute instead; perhaps trying to fiddle with attr rather than text

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can remove `$icon.text(icon);` then text will disapear, and after that just search by class name in your keyup event:

```
$icons.find('i[class*="' + search + '"]').css('display', 'inline-block');
```

Comment: The above worked perfectly.  I had tried fiddling with that line but just wasn't doing the right combination for the class. Thank you!